# UIPopover: filtering another view

Tags: iphone, uipopovercontroller

I have a table that should be filtered and refreshed after clicking on some button (there are several buttons in the popover) of a UIPopover. I have set the popover delegate to the view controller of the table, but I don´t know how to call the UIPopoverControllerDelegate to capture the event of clicking on the button, and to refresh the main table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when any ibaction method of a button called reload your table

```
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: And how should I do it if I use another table in the uipopover? I have tried it by adding a pushviewcontroller in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but it does not work (the pushed view is not loaded).